# How to parse this JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, json

This is not a valid JSON data. But I have to parse it to extract "isNavPaneDisabled". How do I parse it?

```
var text = {
    version: "1.8",
    viewid: "RegistrationPage",
    browserless: false,
    username: "system",
    userrole: "NonAdmin",
    message: "",
    productname: "someApp",
    isNavPaneDisabled: true,
    isDebug: false
};
```

Comment: Why parse? This is JS var. Use it as is: `text.isNavPaneDisabled`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following object isn't in JSON format, but still it's a javaScript object.

```
console.log(typeof text); // it says text is an object
```

So you can access the properties of that object. In your case try,

```
console.log(text.isNavPaneDisabled);
```